# How can I initialize a union(enum) given a comptime string specifying the member in Zig?

Tags: initialization, metaprogramming, zig

Zig has the [`@field`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#field) builtin which allows you to access a `struct`/`union`/`enum` member given a comptime string field name.

E.g., as given by the above link,

```rust
var p = Point{ .x = 0, .y = 0 };

@field(p, "x") = 4;
@field(p, "y") = @field(p, "x") + 1;
```

However, for my specific application, I need to be able to initialize a `union(enum)` given a `comptime []const u8`, and  I would prefer not to do this with an `if`-`else if`-tree to prevent verbosity.

I imagine something much like JavaScript's `["<field-name>"]` member accessing but with static instead of dynamic strings:

```rust
const c = MonochromaticColor{ ["r"] = 255 }; // "MonochromaticColor" is a contrived enum
```

One can emulate the fanciful structure initialization

```rust
const p = Point{ ["x"] = 4, ["y"] = 5 };
```

with

```rust
var p: Point = undefined;
@field(p, "x") = 4;
@field(p, "y") = 5;
```

the trivial disparities between the two notwithstanding.

However, this does not appear to be possible (at least I wasn't able to get it to work) with `union(enum)`s. In any case, I would prefer to avoid the above compromise.

**How can I initialize a `union(enum)` given a comptime string specifying the member in Zig?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via the [`@unionInit`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#unionInit) builtin.

```
const std = @import("std");

const Ex = union(enum) { A: u32, B: []const u8 };

pub fn main() void {
    const example = @unionInit(Ex, "B", "example");
    std.log.info("Example: {any}", .{example});
}
```

Outputs:

```
info: Example: test.Ex{ .B = { 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101 } }
```